# AS2: How do I swapDepth of a Shape and a TextField?

Tags: actionscript-2

**AS2**

```
this.createTextField("lbl_txt", this.getNextHighestDepth(), 70, 5, 150, 30)
lbl_txt.autoSize = true;
lbl_txt.text = "Hello";

var fmt:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
fmt.bold = true;
fmt.color = 0x000000;
fmt.underline = true;
fmt.font = "Arial";
lbl_txt.setTextFormat(fmt);
```

**Timeline Layers**
action
button_layer (button_layer is a animation on rollOver)
arrow
background
**Desired Result**
button_layer and action to be topmost layers and cursor to remain a pointer and not switch to text cursor on rollOver.
action
button_layer
arrow
lbl_txt (TextField created by AS)
background

Comment: You might try creating an empty movie clip as a timeline layer, in the layer position you want, giving it an instance name, and then creating the text field on that empty movie clip. And set the text field ".selectable" property to false to keep your pointer from changing.

Answer (score 0):

```
var textdepth = this.getNextHighestDepth();

//store the depth value somewhere

this.createTextField("lbl_txt", , 70, 5, 150, 30)
lbl_txt.autoSize = true;
lbl_txt.text = "Hello";

var fmt:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
fmt.bold = true;
fmt.color = 0x000000;
fmt.underline = true;
fmt.font = "Arial";
lbl_txt.setTextFormat(fmt);

//now lastly swap it
myMovieClip.swapDepths(textdepth);
```

Note: the swapee should be a movieclip or a button.